# QCA6174 not working in Ubuntu 16.04 after running upgrade yesterday

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04

I already had a problem with this before, and I was able to get it working using the drivers from: github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174.

But after running Ubuntu upgrade (yesterday) I can't get the wifi connection anymore, I created a pastebin with the log of this [here](http://pastebin.com/y6Pyj4nm).

I have tried replacing the firmware again both with the kvalo and the FireWalkerX fork, with no result.

I also tried upgrading the linux-firmware:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
```

I'v also created a pastebin with the output of the wireless-info script recommended in the Ubuntu Forums, [here](http://pastebin.com/Mi6mAqj8) it is.

sudo ethtool -i wlp5s0

```
driver: ath10k_pci
version: 4.5.2-040502-generic
firmware-version: WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:05:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
```

sudo rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the help of a guy from Ubuntu Forums, [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2329509&p=13512625#post13512625).

Here is the code:

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/*
sudo wget https://github.com/FireWalkerX/ath10k-firmware/blob/7e56cbb94182a2fdab110cf5bfeded8fd1d44d30/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin?raw=true /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
sudo wget https://github.com/FireWalkerX/ath10k-firmware/blob/7e56cbb94182a2fdab110cf5bfeded8fd1d44d30/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1?raw=true /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
```

And reboot.

Note that you need to download the board-2.bin and rename it to board.bin.